# how to pass value of viewmodel from controller to another controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to create some application using MVC 4. in my application, i can create new promo. how can i pass value from Create to Index when i using ViewModel for parameter in Index.

this my Index

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel search)
        {
            var RoomType = _RoomTypeService.GetRoomTypeName(_HotelID);
            var currency = _CurrencyService.GetAllCurrency();

            XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel vm = new ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel();

            if (search.Request == null)
            {
                vm.RoomTypeList = ViewModel.DropDown.Builder.RoomTypeBuilder.Build(RoomType, null);
                vm.CurrencyList = ViewModel.DropDown.Builder.CurrencyBuilder.Build(currency, null);
            }
            else
            {
                vm.RoomTypeList = ViewModel.DropDown.Builder.RoomTypeBuilder.Build(RoomType, search.Request.RoomTypeID);
                vm.CurrencyList = ViewModel.DropDown.Builder.CurrencyBuilder.Build(currency, search.Request.Currency);
            }

            vm.Request = search.Request;

            if (search.Request == null)
            {
                vm.Request = new RateRequest();
                vm.Request.CheckInFrom = null;
                vm.Request.CheckInTo = null;
                vm.Request.RoomTypeID = null;
            }
            if (search.Request != null)
            {
                Session["RoomTypeID"] = search.Request.RoomTypeID;
                Session["Breakfast"] = search.Request.Breakfast;
                Session["Currency"] = search.Request.Currency;
            }

            vm.listRoomRate = GetDataIndex(vm.Request);
            _UserSession.SearchRoomRate = vm;
            return RedirectToAction("SearchResult");
        }
```

my New

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel vm)
        {
            if (vm.NewRoomRate.Currency == null)
                vm.NewRoomRate.Currency = "IDR";

            var NewData = _RoomRateService.NewRoomRate(vm.NewRoomRate.RoomTypeName, vm.NewRoomRate.Breakfast,
                                         Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInTo), vm.NewRoomRate.sun, vm.NewRoomRate.mon, vm.NewRoomRate.tue,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.wed, vm.NewRoomRate.thu, vm.NewRoomRate.fri, vm.NewRoomRate.sat, vm.NewRoomRate.Currency, vm.NewRoomRate.SingleRate,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.DoubleRate, vm.NewRoomRate.TripleRate, Convert.ToDecimal(vm.NewRoomRate.Commision), Convert.ToInt32(vm.NewRoomRate.Allotment), vm.NewRoomRate.CloseSelling,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.FreeSell);

            if (NewData == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("failed", "RoomRate is already created, please use edit instead");
                return New();
            }

            ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel test = new ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel();
            test.Request = new RateRequest();
            test.Request.RoomTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(vm.NewRoomRate.RoomTypeName);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = test.Request });
        }
```

i try like this, but i get error like this

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.RateRequest]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel'.
```

can some one tell me, how i can do this?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

according to the error you are getting:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.RateRequest]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'XNet.WebUI.Hotel.ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel'.
```

you are specifying that Index will recieve a parameter of type: `ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel` named search.

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel search)
```

but you are passing an object of type `ViewModel.Rate.RateViewMode` in your "NEW" action result.

```
ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel test = new ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel();
            test.Request = new RateRequest();
            test.Request.RoomTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(vm.NewRoomRate.RoomTypeName);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = test.Request });
```

to resolve the error you can edit your controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel vm)
        {
            if (vm.NewRoomRate.Currency == null)
                vm.NewRoomRate.Currency = "IDR";

            var NewData = _RoomRateService.NewRoomRate(vm.NewRoomRate.RoomTypeName, vm.NewRoomRate.Breakfast,
                                         Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInFrom), Convert.ToDateTime(vm.NewRoomRate.CheckInTo), vm.NewRoomRate.sun, vm.NewRoomRate.mon, vm.NewRoomRate.tue,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.wed, vm.NewRoomRate.thu, vm.NewRoomRate.fri, vm.NewRoomRate.sat, vm.NewRoomRate.Currency, vm.NewRoomRate.SingleRate,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.DoubleRate, vm.NewRoomRate.TripleRate, Convert.ToDecimal(vm.NewRoomRate.Commision), Convert.ToInt32(vm.NewRoomRate.Allotment), vm.NewRoomRate.CloseSelling,
                                         vm.NewRoomRate.FreeSell);

            if (NewData == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("failed", "RoomRate is already created, please use edit instead");
                return New();
            }

            ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel test = new ViewModel.Rate.RateViewModel();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {search = test });
        }
```

hope that helps.